# Can't create build for android cause of this issue: Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a build for android from the react native start app and I can't cause the following error is showing up:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file '/Users/carlos2/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/settings.gradle.kts' line: 16
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention:org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention.gradle.plugin:0.5.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  MavenRepo
  Google
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> BUILD FAILED in 9s
> error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where:
> Settings file '/Users/carlos2/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/settings.gradle.kts' line: 16 * What went wrong:
> Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources: - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention:org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention.gradle.plugin:0.5.0') Searched in the following repositories: MavenRepo Google Gradle Central Plugin Repository * Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 9s.
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

I have tried almost everything to solve this and I'm very sick of this issues.